# Check multiple regex on every string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with roles which looks like this :

```
["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_MARKETING"]
```

**What I need** :
I need to check if in this array, a `string` match EXACTLY. If yes, `return true`, if no `return false`.

**Warning**:
As you can see below, there are `roles` that start with same text, so it is important to check the exact same string.

Why my `console.log` returns `true` here ? Maybe I shouldn't use `switch` case ?

```
export const ROLE_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";
export const ROLE_USER_ADMIN = "ROLE_USER_ADMIN";
export const ROLE_MARKETING = "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_MARKETING";
export const ROLE_TECHNICAL = "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_TECHNICAL";

const roles: string[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("roles"));

class UserRole {
    static regexAdmin = new RegExp(`\\b${ROLE_ADMIN}\\b`);
    static regexUserAdmin = new RegExp(`\\b${ROLE_USER_ADMIN}\\b`);
    static regexMarketing = new RegExp(`\\b${ROLE_MARKETING}\\b`);
    static regexTechnical = new RegExp(`\\b${ROLE_TECHNICAL}\\b`);

    public static hasAuthorization(role: string): boolean {
        for (const role of roles) {
            switch (true) {
                case UserRole.regexAdmin.test(role):
                    return true;
                case UserRole.regexUserAdmin.test(role):
                    return true;
                case UserRole.regexMarketing.test(role):
                    return true;
                case UserRole.regexTechnical.test(role):
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

export const hasAdmin = UserRole.hasAuthorization(ROLE_USER_ADMIN);

console.log(hasAdmin); // THIS RETURNS TRUE
```

Comment: Please never use a switch with `switch (true)` that is an abuse of the switch statement

Comment: After your comments under my answer, I suspect `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("roles"));` doesn't return what you expect. Can you verify it returns `["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_MARKETING"]`?

Comment: `for (const role of roles) {` shadows the parameter `role: string`. You're completely ignoring the argument and only comparing `roles` from local storage with the hard coded regexes. Your loop always returns in the first iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems in your code:

`for (const role of roles) {` shadows the parameter `role: string`. You're completely ignoring the argument and only comparing `roles` from local storage with the hard coded regexes. Your loop always returns in the first iteration.

My solution:

A regex isn't necessary. It's a simple

```
["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_MARKETING"].includes(ROLE_USER_ADMIN)
```

Example:

```js
let ROLE_USER_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";

console.log(["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_MARKETING"].includes(ROLE_USER_ADMIN));

ROLE_USER_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN2";

console.log(["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_MARKETING"].includes(ROLE_USER_ADMIN));

ROLE_USER_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMI";

console.log(["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_MARKETING"].includes(ROLE_USER_ADMIN));
```

The full code could be

```
export const ROLE_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";
export const ROLE_USER_ADMIN = "ROLE_USER_ADMIN";
export const ROLE_MARKETING = "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_MARKETING";
export const ROLE_TECHNICAL = "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_TECHNICAL";

const roles: string[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("roles"));

class UserRole {
    public static hasAuthorization(role: string): boolean {
        return roles.includes(role);
    }
}

export const hasAdmin = UserRole.hasAuthorization(ROLE_USER_ADMIN);

console.log(hasAdmin); // THIS RETURNS TRUE
```

Example:

```js
const ROLE_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";
const ROLE_USER_ADMIN = "ROLE_USER_ADMIN";
const ROLE_MARKETING = "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_MARKETING";
const ROLE_TECHNICAL = "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_TECHNICAL";
    
const roles = ["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER_ADMIN_MARKETING"];
    
class UserRole {
    static hasAuthorization(role) {
        return roles.includes(role);
    }
}
    
const hasAdmin = UserRole.hasAuthorization(ROLE_USER_ADMIN);
const hasMarketing = UserRole.hasAuthorization(ROLE_MARKETING);
    
console.log(hasAdmin); // THIS RETURNS FALSE
console.log(hasMarketing); // THIS RETURNS TRUE
```

Comment: includes does not check if string match EXACTLY.

Comment: @Johan Of course, it does. I added an example.

Comment: the console still returns true with your code. And `ROLE_USER_ADMIN` is not the same as `ROLE_USER_ADMIN_MARKETING`

Comment: @mplungjan `roles` is an array. `roles.includes` is `Array.prototype.includes`.

Comment: @Johan I added another example. It works.